# EISDIR after adding React Navigation to the project

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I added react navigation to my project. I installed it like it is written in their docs, but it tells me:

```
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
    at Object.readSync (fs.js:577:3)
    at tryReadSync (fs.js:353:20)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:390:19)
    at UnableToResolveError.buildCodeFrameMessage (/Users/administrator/globo/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:347:17)
    at new UnableToResolveError (/Users/administrator/globo/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:333:35)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/administrator/globo/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:211:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/administrator/globo/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:413:43)
    at /Users/administrator/globo/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:317:42
    at /Users/administrator/globo/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:1471:14
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "start": "expo start -c",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.4",
    "expo": "~40.0.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.8.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.3",
    "expo-updates": "~0.4.0",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "^0.64.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.8.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.15.0",
    "react-native-unimodules": "^0.13.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.15.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "babel-jest": "~25.2.6",
    "jest": "~25.2.6",
    "react-test-renderer": "~16.13.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I don't know what should I add, so please ask questions if you need. Please help. I am new in React Native.